# java call eclipse's ant API

Tags: java, ant, eclipse-plugin

In my java program, I want to call eclipse ant to build jar file, how I can get eclipse's ant API.I can build jar file by Runtime.getRuntime.exec("call ant build"),however users must have install ant.We know eclipse has ant, so I want to call eclipse'ant to build my jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use the normal Ant Java API you just need to set up your classpath to the Ant installation included in Eclipse. Eclipse has the Ant jars in the `plugins/org.apache.ant_xxx/lib` directory in the installation directory.

A problem is the `xxx` in the org.apache.ant_xxx directory name which will be something like `1.8.4.v201303080030` but varies depending on the exact Eclipse release that is installed.

Comment: 'File buildFile = new File("build.xml");
Project p = new Project();  
DefaultLogger consoleLogger = new DefaultLogger();
consoleLogger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
consoleLogger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
consoleLogger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
p.addBuildListener(consoleLogger);
try {
 p.fireBuildStarted();
 p.init();
 ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
 helper.parse(p, buildFile);
 p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
 p.fireBuildFinished(null);
} catch (BuildException e) {
 p.fireBuildFinished(e);
}'  **I should to call ant api like this?**

Comment: That is the normal Ant Java API

Comment: Sorry I don't understand it. I try this method,but failed.

Comment: BuildException is in the ant.jar

Comment: I hava import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;

Answer (score 0):

1.You could use build.xml which ant need , then write the necessary code in it.You could Google the detail usage.After you finish,right click the build.xml and choose Run as-->ant build.

2.You could use Export function to export jar.It seems to be in File column in Eclipse.

3.Or you just want to generate jar in main class while the program is running?